# What is the hash of this cipher: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CCM

Tags: tls, gcm, ccm

In TLS 1.3 supported ciphersuite,  I find the following ciphersuite:

> TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CCM

Can any one tell me what is the hash function used in this ciphersuite? how could you know that (reference please).

Comment: CCM uses CBC-MAC for authentication. It's mentioned here: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6655.

Comment: And for the PRF it uses SHA256, also in the rfc.

Comment: Where did you find it for TLS 1.3? As in draft 15, appendix A.4.: "   Although TLS 1.3 uses the same cipher suite space as previous
   versions of TLS, TLS 1.3 cipher suites are defined differently, only
   specifying the symmetric ciphers, and cannot it be used for TLS 1.2.
   Similarly, TLS 1.2 and lower cipher suites cannot be used with TLS
   1.3."

Comment: @Maarten Bodewes I found it in draft 14 section: (A.4. Cipher Suites).

Comment: Please use the latest draft. Furthermore, I can not see that cipher, only  TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CCM ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In draft 14, *which is not the latest draft* at the time of writing there are two places where a hash is used: the one for signature generation / verification using the private key / public key pair of the leaf certificate and the one used as configuration parameter for HKDF (session key derivation)

### For signature generation / verification

`TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CCM` doesn't exist, only  TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CCM exists which is similar but uses a different key agreement protocol. RSA for key agreement was explicitly deprecated for TLS 1.3. In the RFC the ciphersuite can be represented by [`TLS_AES_128_CCM_SHA256`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8446#appendix-B.4); beware that the DH key agreement scheme - if that is used instead of ECDH - differs ever so slightly though (disclosure: sorry, I did that).

RSA uses the `supported_signature_algorithms` extension to select the hash configuration parameter within the signature generation function. This is specified clearly in [section 4.2.2.  Signature Algorithms](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-tls-tls13-14#section-4.2.2).

### For key derivation

The hash is after the (EC)DHE key agreement operation to derive the session keys. This will always use HKDF, as specified in [appendix A.4](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-tls-tls13-14#appendix-A.4):

> Cipher suite names that lack a "HASH" value that are defined for use
> with TLS 1.2 or later use the SHA-256 hash algorithm by default.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sorry for the type. No RSA. I meant DHE_RSA. But, for key derivation, there is a log used as input for the kdf. This log is a hash of the transcript. Which hash function (algorithm) is used in the log that is input of kdf? which hash algorithm is used in the log that is input of signature? which hash algorithm is used in the log that is input of the finish MAC? I am confused.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't see any mention of a log. If you cannot even keep to the terminology and definitions in the standard, how the hell am I supposed to be able to answer you? References please!

Comment: Here is the ref. (see the TLS 1.3 diagram in p. 33) https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/072.pdf

Comment: @kelalaka Fixed. Or do you still see issues? Comment if you do.

Answer (score 0):

The bottom line regarding the hashes is:

1. The signature in the server's certificate uses double hashes. The first (inner) hash is the HKDF which is the ciphersuite hash. The second (outer) uses the hash in the signature_algorithms extension
2. Other hashes for the exchanged messages which I referred to them by (logs) - based on the terminologies used in this reference: https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/072.pdf (specifically, the simplified TLS 1.3 diagram in pp. 33) uses the hash specified in the ciphersuite.

Comment: HKDF is not a hash function.